# Translating GlobalPlatform from C to Delphi - Access violation errors

Tags: c++, delphi, dll, smartcard, globalplatform

I want to use the GlobalPlatform.dll from [kaoh Karsten Ohme](https://github.com/kaoh/globalplatform) in Delphi. So i tried to translate the headers so i can use the GlobalPlatform.dll in Delphi.

The first i translated was Connection.h, [i uploaded it on pastebin here](https://pastebin.com/cCVZMaq3).
The second i translated was Security.h [i uploaded it on pastebin here.](https://pastebin.com/6mJ9D5GB)

First i establish a context with the `OPGP_establish_context` function, that seems to go alright because the result is a `OPGP_ERROR_STATUS_SUCCESS` and the message also states "success".

But then i try to list the readers with the `OPGP_list_readers` function, which also returns a success - but when i try to read the returned names i get various access violations (mostly at `adress 00000000 and trying to read 00000000`, but there are variations between my tries).

My code is assigned to a button click:

```
procedure TfrmFormatCard.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  BUFLEN = 1024;
var
  Status,
  Status2 : OPGP_ERROR_STATUS;
  Context : OPGP_CARD_CONTEXT;
  Names   : array [0..BUFLEN +1] of Char;
  Len     : DWord;
begin
  Context.libraryName    := 'gppcscconnectionplugin';
  Context.libraryVersion := '211';
  Status := OPGP_establish_context(Context);
  if Status.errorStatus = OPGP_ERROR_STATUS_SUCCESS then
  begin
    Len := 1024;
    Status2 := OPGP_list_readers(Context, Names, Len);
    if Status2.errorStatus = OPGP_ERROR_STATUS_SUCCESS then
    begin
      // Messagebox(application.Handle, names, '', 0);
    end;
    OPGP_release_context(Context);
  end;
end;
```

When i use the above code i get no errors, but when i uncomment the messagebox - i get the access violations. I have been trying all day, and i modified everything .. but no luck. I can't see what im doing wrong. Maybe someone can help me out and point me in the right direction. I understand what a access violation on `adress 00000000` means, but i dont know if i translated the headers the right way what might cause the error.

If someone could help me by checking, or testing it themselves - that would be highly appreciated.

I am using Delphi 10.4, and i have a internal smartcard reader (in the laptop), a Omnikey smartcard reader, and another unknown brand.

ps. Yes i am aware of the GPShell commandline utility, but i would like to avoid having to use that. I want to use smartcards for security, and the need for the commandline tool would make this a weak point - hence why i want to use the Library directly.

Comment: This looks suspicious: `libraryName         : array [0..64] of Char;` (as do others). That array is 65 characters long. Without looking at the original code I suspect it should be: `libraryName         : array [0..63] of Char;`, which has a length of 64

Comment: When i change it to array [0..63] i get access violation errors. Also when i change it to [1..64], at this point i dont know if that is because of this change - or just because somewhere else is the problem and this just causes the access violation to popup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the 1st record you translated, `OPGP_ERROR_STATUS`, the `errorMessage` field is declared in the C code as:

```c
TCHAR errorMessage[ERROR_MESSAGE_LENGTH+1];
```

where `ERROR_MESSAGE_LENGTH` is defined as 256, thus this array has **257 chars** max.

But your translation:

```pascal
errorMessage : array [0..ERROR_MESSAGE_LENGTH + 1] of Char;
```

has **258 chars** max. This is because an [array declaration in Delphi](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Arrays) defines the *indexes* of the array, inclusive, so in your case you are declaring the array as having indexes `0..257`, but it should be `0..256` instead, so drop the `+1`:

```pascal
errorMessage : array [0..ERROR_MESSAGE_LENGTH] of Char;
```

You are making that same mistake in your translation of the `OPGP_CARD_CONTEXT` record, too:

```pascal
OPGP_CARD_CONTEXT = record
  librarySpecific     : Pointer;
  libraryName         : array [0..64] of Char; // <--
  libraryVersion      : array [0..32] of Char; // <--
  libraryHandle       : Pointer;
  connectionFunctions : OPGP_CONNECTION_FUNCTIONS;
end;
```

You are declaring `libraryName` as having **65 chars**, and `libraryVersion` as having **33 chars**.  They need to be **64** and **32** instead, respectively:

```
OPGP_CARD_CONTEXT = record
  librarySpecific     : Pointer;
  libraryName         : array [0..63] of Char;
  libraryVersion      : array [0..31] of Char;
  libraryHandle       : Pointer;
  connectionFunctions : OPGP_CONNECTION_FUNCTIONS;
end;
```

Per the original C declaration:

```c
typedef struct {
    PVOID librarySpecific; //!< Library specific data.
    TCHAR libraryName[64]; //!< The name of the connection library to use.
    TCHAR libraryVersion[32]; //!< The version of the connection library to use.
    PVOID libraryHandle; //!< The handle to the library.
    OPGP_CONNECTION_FUNCTIONS connectionFunctions; //!< Connection functions of the connection library. Is automatically filled in if the connection library can be loaded correctly.
} OPGP_CARD_CONTEXT;
```

So, it makes sense why an AV could occur, since `OPGP_list_readers()` internally accesses function pointers that are stored in the `Context.connectionFunctions` field following the arrays, thus the pointers would be accessed at the wrong memory offsets.

Something else to watch out for is `TCHAR`, which will map to either `char` or `wchar_t` depending on how the DLL is actually compiled. So that *may or may not* translate to `Char` in Delphi, depending on what version you are using (which you didn't say). In general, `char` -> `AnsiChar`, `wchar_t` -> `WideChar`. The project's `unicode.h` file suggests non-Windows builds are compiled to use `char`. But the project makefile suggests the Windows build is compiled to use `wchar_t` instead.  It is not a good idea to use `(P)Char` in interop code because of this.  Use `(P)AnsiChar` or `(P)WideChar` as needed instead.

**UPDATE**

Also, try zeroing out the memory of the `Context` before passing it to `OPGP_establish_context()`. The first thing `OPGP_establish_context()` does internally is call `OPGP_release_context()` on the `Context`, which means the `Context` can't contain any garbage in it (particularly in the `libraryHandle` and `connectionFunctions.releaseContext` fields) or else it will be mishandled.

Comment: Thank you, i edited the length's so they are the right length. But now i get a error when i call OPGP_establish_context.


`Context.libraryName    := 'gppcscconnectionplugin';
Context.libraryVersion := '211';
Status := OPGP_establish_context(Context);`


I only have these three lines of code, and i get a Access violation at address 002DB020. Write of address 008E6620.

Comment: Thank you! I checked everything, and the problem seemed to be that i declared the array's as [0..64] where they needed to be [1..64]. So the DLL expects the (char) array to start at 1 instead of 0. This combined with your answers did it for me! Thank you very much, you made my day!!

Comment: "*So the DLL expects the (char) array to start at 1 instead of 0*" - that is incorrect. The DLL is written in C, and in C all arrays start at index 0. The real issue is as I (and Dave) stated earlier - `[0..64]` creates an array with **65** elements, whereas `[1..64]` contains **64** elements. The DLL expects 64 in this case. You are over-allocating your arrays.

Comment: Okay thank you for clarifying. That makes sense indeed. I do have a new problem popping up - but i will ask that in a separate thread.

Comment: And a big thank you for the update - i added ZeroMemory(@Context, SizeOf(Context)); at the start of the procedure, and this fixed the error i was still getting. :)